# Router shows assigned ip but pc receives 169.x.x.x

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router

So the computer of my friend when she tries to connect to the wifi it show that is connected but with out internet receiving the 169.x.x.x, but when i go to the router it shows that is assigning the ip 192.x.x.x. When i change her ip on the computer to the static ip i have assigned her in the router it gives her internet.

The same has happened to my android this morning but after some time it gave internet again.

Does anyone have any ideia why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the host device is having trouble communicating with the dhcp server, which I can assume is your home router, when this happens it assigns itself an ip address of 169.x.x.x, this is so that it can still communicate with other hosts on that subnet.

I would try a few things to try and resolve this issue.

1. Simply try rebooting both t he router and host device.
2. If that doesn't work try running these commands:

   - `ipconfig /release` to release your leased IP address from the DHCP server
   - `ipconfig /flushdns` to flush the DNS server
   - `ipconfig /renew` to acquire a new IP address
3. Failing the above methods, I would try either updating or uninstalling/reinstalling the appropriate wifi/LAN network drivers.
4. Failing that, it could be a hardware issue.

Comment: I have a clue that might be it, a few days ago before i acquired the new wireless router my modem of the isp was always turning off and i called them and they told me it was a problem on the phone line because i have ADSL cable.